# AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'add_dll_directory' when running ANY CODE in Jupyter Notebooks Python 39?

Tags: python, pandas, attributeerror

This was never a problem until today.

I installed pyreadstat and after that I started getting this error: AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'add_dll_directory' if I run ANY code.

For example, if I run "import pandas as pd" i get this code.

I have already restarted the kernal as well as uninstalled and re-installed both pandas and pyreadstat. I have no idea where to start and google searches on this topic are not helpful at all. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image: pandas issue]

Comment: `import os; print(os.__file__)` and show us what that prints.

Comment: Also `import sys; print(sys.version)`.